# Cannot find jni.h

Tags: java, c, gcc, java-native-interface

I am trying to setup a JNI demo example and got stuck at exporting a library on Windows OS.

According to [this](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni) tutorial, the following command should be executed:

```
gcc -o libctest.so -shared -I/path/to/jdk/headers ctest.c -lc
```

where the `/path/to/jdk/headers` refers to the directory that contains `jni.h`.

This is how invoke the command:

```
gcc -o ctest.dll -shared -I/"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include" ctest.c -lc
```

and the result was:

```
jni.h: no such file or directory.
include jni.h
```

I have checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529720/how-to-make-jni-h-be-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466777/jni-h-no-such-file-or-directory), which seems to suggest pretty much what I did.

The code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_helloFromC
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
{
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

How do I get around this error?

Comment: Why not search the drive for the `jni.h` file? Either you will find it in another location, or you won't find it meaning your JDK isn't properly installed.

Comment: The jni.h is there actually, this is what is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
gcc -o ctest.dll -shared -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\include" ctest.c -lc
```

Note that after `-I` the slash character is not there anymore and the delimiter is set to backslash (the Windows delimiter).

Comment: Wow i am silly :) Well that did get me around that error. It exploded with missing jndi_md.h but managed to resolve it with another -I to relevant directory.