# Android JNI ndk-build error: 'jni' has not been declared

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to use dynamic registration in native method, so I need set `JNI_onLoad` function. I just write a function to get sum of two numbers. But, it can't build correctly. How can I correct the error?

- This is my *.cpp file, I name this file `jni.cpp`

  ```
  #include <jni.h>
  extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {

      jni::JNIEnv& env = jni::GetEnv(*vm, jni::jni_version_1_6);
      jni::jclass& nativeClass = jni::FindClass(env, "com/test/NativeClass");

      #define MAKE_NATIVE_METHOD(name, sig) jni::MakeNativeMethod<decltype(name), name>( #name, sig )
      jni::RegisterNatives(env, nativeClass, MAKE_NATIVE_METHOD(nativeAddTest, "(II)I")        );

      return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
   }

  jlong nativeAddTest(JNIEnv *env, jni::jobject* obj, jni::jint a, jni::jint b) {
      return a+b;
  }
  ```
- `Android.mk`

  ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := test
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni.cpp
   LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/ndk-path/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  ```
- When I use `ndk-build` command, it's wrong. But I really dont't konw the reason...

  ```
  D:\WorkSpaces\Test\app\src\main\jni>ndk-build
    [x86] Compile++      : test <= jni.cpp
  D:/WorkSpaces/Test/app/src/main/jni/jni.cpp: In function 'jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)':
  D:/WorkSpaces/Test/app/src/main/jni/jni.cpp:9:5: error: 'jni' has not been declared
     jni::JNIEnv& env = jni::GetEnv(*vm, jni::jni_version_1_6);
     ^
  D:/WorkSpaces/Test/app/src/main/jni/jni.cpp:9:18: error: 'env' was not declared in this scope
     jni::JNIEnv& env = jni::GetEnv(*vm, jni::jni_version_1_6);
  ....
  ```

It seems can't find ***jni.h***, but I already have `#include<jni.h>`

Answer (score 2):

In Android NDK, **<jni.h>** does not define a **jni** namespace. Simply remove all **jni::**

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {

   JNIEnv env;
   vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6);
   jclass nativeClass = env->FindClass("com/test/NativeClass");
```

… and so on.

Comment: But if I remove all `jni::`, the error become `jni_version_1_6`, `GetEnv` or others filed was not declared in this scope.

Comment: I have upload this project to [github.com](https://github.com/kevin4z/DynamicJNI), can you help me modify that? I really don't know how to use `JNI`. Thanks :)

Comment: please see the update. I don't know where you took your template, but it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add header location to your android.mk

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := "path to your header location"
```

Comment: Is the `jni.h` file location? I add this line but it also has seemly build error.`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := D:\Android\android-ndk-r10e\platforms\android-21\arch-arm\usr\include`

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466777/jni-h-no-such-file-or-directory