# Makefile: Fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory

Tags: java, makefile, raspberry-pi, java-native-interface, raspbian

I am trying to `make` [this library](https://github.com/olir/lbt4j) and I am following instructions in **Maven** paragraph. However, I fail on step

```
make clean all
```

with the following error:

> ObjectManager.c:35:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
>   `#include <jni.h>`

So, following answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466777/jni-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529720/how-to-make-jni-h-be-found) I am trying to add the location of `jni.h` file to compiler flags. In my case, this file is located in

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include
```

What I have tried so far:

`make -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include clean all`
`make -I"${JAVA_HOME}/include" -I"${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux" clean all`
`export JAVA_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include`

In short, none of the proposed solutions worked and makefile still fails with the same error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library already has the correct settings [see CFLAGS]. From its makefile in target/jni:

```
IDIR =./include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-fPIC -Wall -g -I. -I$(IDIR) -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKGDEPS))
```

This most likely means your JAVA_HOME is not set correctly.